# What is the scope of global variables in the views.py?

Tags: django, scope

If I declare a global variable `myglobalvar` in my views.py

```
myglobalvar = "value"

def home(request):
    print(myglobalvar)

def thatOneLink(request):
    myglobalvar = "different value"
```

When someone calls `thatOneLink` what is the scope of the change? Will `myglobalvar = "different value"` only for this request? Or only for the session? Or until the server restarts?

In JSP by default there were settings on the scope. Django seems to have another package for that: https://pypi.org/project/django-scopes/
But in the very default case without any additional packages, how does Django handle scopes? Or do they have different names or definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python as a language has the concept of scoping and global variables. The same applies here regardless of Django. See this example

```
x = 10

def first():
    x = 20
    print(x)

def second():
    global x
    print(x)
    x = 30
    print(x)

def third():
    print(x)


first()
second()
third()
```

Output

```
20
10
30
30
```

In the `first` function x is redeclared with a new value and has no effect on the outer value. The function `second` prints the `x` just to verify that and then makes x global using the `global` keyword. Now, `x` is reinitialized in the outer scope, and function `third` confirms that.

In particular to your scenario, `myglobalvar` will only change for that particular request and the outer scope value will remain unchanged. However, if you use the `global` keyword.

```
global myglobalvar
myglobalvar = "different value"
```

inside `thatOneLink`, the value of `myglobalvar` will change for all the requests served by that process (even for all threads in that process) until you restart the process.

Comment: Until when will the change persist? Until I restart the server? Also, if other users join, which values will they get?

Comment: Yes, until you restart the server. But it depends on the process. Usually, in a production environment you use WSGI servers like [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) which use multiple processes, so the value will be changed for requests served by one process once the function hits for that process. If you are trying to use this approach for persisting some value, it is a very very bad idea. Use something like Redis with Django's built-in cache module. And yes, once changed it will remain changed for all the users served by that process. until the process is restarted.